# Switch div content JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I would like to know how to change divs content with js or jQuery. I have a div with `id="container"` which include 5 more divs with different id's. What I need is to start with first div with `id="vapor"` then, by clicking on a button to change onto next div with `id="baiat"` and so on. Here's my code, I couldn't add any js or jQuery:

```
<div id="container" class="thirdcanvas">
      
       <div id="vapor">
           <img src="images/alfabet/w.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/f.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/v.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/o.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/r.png" alt=""/>
       </div>
       
       <div id="baiat">
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/aa.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/t.png" alt=""/>
       </div>     
           
       <div id="colac">    
           <img src="images/alfabet/g.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/c.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/u.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/o.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/c.png" alt=""/>
       </div> 
           
       <div id="slapi">    
           <img src="images/alfabet/s.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/ss.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
       </div>  
           
       <div id="umbrela">   
           <img src="images/alfabet/u.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/n.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/m.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/r.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/e.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
       </div>  
   </div>
```

I have now this code:

```
var image = new Array("images/baiat.png", "images/colac.png" , "images/slapi.png" , "images/umbrela.png");

var imgNumber=0; 

var numberOfImg = image.length;

function nextImage(){
    
    $("#container div").not("#container div:first").each(function(){

    $(this).addClass('hidden');

});

$("#click").click(function(){

    var divWithoutHiddenClass=$("#container div").not("#container div.hidden");       
    
   divWithoutHiddenClass.addClass('hidden');
         
       if(divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html()===undefined){
           $("#container div:first").removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else{
        divWithoutHiddenClass.next().removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
    
  if(imgNumber < numberOfImg){
    imgNumber++;
    }
  document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1];
 
 }
 
 
            
if(document.images){
   
   var image1 = new Image();
   image1.src = "images/vapor.png";
   var image2 = new Image();
   image2.src = "images/baiat.png";
   var image3 = new Image();
   image3.src = "images/colac.png";
   var image4 = new Image();
   image4.src = "images/slapi.png";
   var image5 = new Image();
   image5.src = "images/umbrela.png";
   
   }
```

with :

```
<a href="#" onClick="nextImage()"><img id="click" src="images/nextBtn.png" title="Continuare" /></a>
```

Comment: On first button click you want all images from baiat put in vapor div?

Comment: What kind of output you want.You need to add more info

Comment: Nope,on page load i would like to have all images from vapor onto container,then on first click i want to change container with images from baiat,then container change its load with images from colac by clicking 2nd time

Comment: I would like to clear the previous info from vapor div and fill with baiat elements and so on

Comment: @OzZie do you mean dynamically loading content, or just show and hiding different divs?

Comment: Well,dynamically loading content would be great.Starting with first div that has images then clicking on a button and changing into next one

Comment: @OzZie can you be more specific when you say "changing into"?
i.e. make visible/hide, move the order of the `divs`, replace the content of the `divs` with each other...
As Zword suggested, could you provide more context on what you are trying to achieve. i.e. is this a gallery view, etc?

Comment: Ok,when i'm loading the page i would like to have <div id="vapor"> with all its elements. Then click on a button and clear the div or change its content into <div id="baiat"> elements

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/czR9j/ I don't have images, so there are numbers (div content) instead.

Comment: Replace the content of the divs its what i need. Its like a slideing gallery

Comment: @tilda yeah!! this is it..Thanks all of you and sorry i couldnt explain it better :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czR9j/1/)

**JS**

```
$("#container div").not("#container div:first").each(function(){

    $(this).addClass('hidden');

});

    $("#click").click(function(){

        var divWithoutHiddenClass=$("#container div").not("#container div.hidden");       

       divWithoutHiddenClass.addClass('hidden');

           if(divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html()===undefined){
               $("#container div:first").removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else{
            divWithoutHiddenClass.next().removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

Comment: One more wish if you can help me? there's a problem...on page load all content is there not just the first one as in your fiddle :( and i've tryed to make on this line <a href="#" onClick="nextImage()"><img id="click" src="images/nextBtn.png" title="Continuare" ></a> the next button instead of unput method

Comment: @Zword you get a vote up coz you're code its good but tilda's code its easy and does the thing i need

Comment: each function hide all divs(except first). Did you add it? It doesn't depend on button.

Comment: I added js,css you wrote on fiddle and instead of input i made id="click" on another line of code.On fiddle looks great,next button works properly and i have an ideea to make a for with contor to make it stop when it reach last div

Comment: nextImage() has to be called on page load to hide all divs (but first!).

Comment: pff :( does strange things ... i thought if you or someone else can help me with div changing i can add it on nextImage() function i have for changing 5 pictures.At the final i wanted to get on page load first picture and first div (vapor) then clicking on a button to change the picture and the div ( onto baiat div)

Answer (score 2):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jA5Se/2/)

```
var parentElem = $('#container');
var parentWidth=parentElem.outerWidth();

$('#left').click(function(){
    var sr=parentElem.scrollLeft();
    parentElem.scrollLeft(sr-parentWidth); 
});

$('#right').click(function(){
   var sr=parentElem.scrollLeft();
   parentElem.scrollLeft(sr+parentWidth); 
});
```